# Homomorphism Between a Geometric Algebra and its Field of Scalars?

Tags: abstract-algebra, real-numbers, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

Given a geometric algebra defined over a real vector space, is is possible to construct a homomorphism between the elements of the geometric algebra and the reals?

I was pondering an example of this: constructing an algebra homomorphism between the complex numbers and the real numbers. I have a hunch that it isn't not possible, but I'm not sure why it wouldn't be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An algebra-homorphism is (among other things) a vector-space morphism, so a linear map. In particular, if you map from a $m$-dimensional space to a $1$-dimensional space it should have a $(m-1)$-dimensional kernel. Let's call this subspace $K$ and the full algebra $A$. Now we use the other face of algebra homomorphism, namely that it respects multiplication. Let $k$ be an element of $K$ and let $a$ be a random other element of $A$. Let $\phi$ be the homomorphism. We have $\phi(ak) = \phi(a)\phi(k) = \phi(a)*0 = 0$ so $\phi$ maps $ak$ to $0$. But being mapped to zero under $\phi$ is the definition of lying in the kernel of $\phi$, so we see that $ak \in K$ for all $a$ in the algebra and all $k \in K$.

In other words: $K$ is an ideal of the algebra. (I show here that it is a left ideal, but by the same reasoning we can show it is a two-sided ideal.)

$\mathbb{C}$ doesn't have any non-trivial ideals because it is a field: the fact that every element has an inverse prevents the '$ak \in K$ for every $a \in A, k \in K$'-behavior. The reason is simple: if $ak \in K$ for every $a$ then in particular $1 = k^{-1}k \in K$ and hence $a = a1 \in K$ for every $a$ in the algebra. But since $K$ was defined as the kernel of $\phi$ this would mean that $\phi$ maps EVERY element of $\mathbb{C}$ to zero. Ok, strictly speaking this is a homomorphism, but probably not one of the kind you are interested in.

A bit harder to show is that other geometric algebras such as $Mat(2, \mathbb{R})$ do not have non-trivial two-sided ideals (in particular because it does have left-ideals and right-ideals) and hence no homomorphism to the ground field. Perhaps google for Wedderburn Structure Theorem to learn more about this.

By contrast: here is an example of an algebra that does have a homomorphism to the ground field: the algebra of all $n \times n$ upper triangular matrices. In fact it has (at least, but my gut feeling is exactly) $n$ such homomorphisms.

Comment: This answer is great, thanks!

Would it be possible to construct a homomorphism between a geometric algebra $A$ of a vector space $V$ and a geometric algebra $B$ of a non-trivial subspace $W$? 

It seems as though your argument  relies on the fact that every non-zero element of $\mathbb{C}$ has a multiplicative inverse and that we may choose a non-zero element of the kernel. If $\phi: A \to B$ and we are not guaranteed that every non-zero element of $A$ has an inverse (which I've gathered from [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4361175/)), does it still hold?

Comment: Yes, the upper triangular matrix algebra has exactly $n$ homomorphisms to its base field, corresponding to the maximal ideals, which are those where you zero out a diagonal element.

Comment: Yes, what I mean is that the presence of all those right ideals make it harder to show that there are no *two-sided* ideals. Of course 'something making the proof of something else harder' is a very informal (ill defined) concept, but to get a taste of what I mean: here are two proof strategies for proving that no two sided ideals exist that cannot work because of there being inf. many right ideals: 1) show that there are no right ideals (and then conclude that there can not be any two sided ideals either) 2) Make a list of all right ideals and check one by one that they are not left ideals.

Comment: The statement that there are no two sided ideals in $Mat(2, R)$ is still true, but we need a proof that is smarter than the two ideas in the previous comment.

Comment: @Vincent hi, I reread this today and I have no idea what was going through my head. Please forget I said anything. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean *algebra* (or just ring) homomorphism, since it's trivial to find vector space homomorphisms.

If you are mainly interested in the Clifford algebras for *nondegenerate forms*, then the [classification theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_Clifford_algebras) explain when this happens.

Basically they say that Clifford algebras (for nondegenerate real or complex forms) are of the form $R$ or $R\times R$ where $R$ is a matrix ring over a division ring.

Such a ring has, respectively, two or four ideals that could serve as the kernel of the homomorphism you're talking about, and the resulting quotient ring would have to be $1$ dimensional over $\mathbb R$, so we see that the only two possibilities are either just $\mathbb R$ itself, or $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$.

So $CL_{0,0}(\mathbb R)$ and $CL_{1,0}(\mathbb R)$ are the only ones that permit a ring homomorphism onto $\mathbb R$.

An algebra between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ is impossible simply for the reason that $\mathbb C$ has no nontrivial ideals. The image of any homomorphism out of $\mathbb C$ will be $\{0\}$ or isomorphic to $\mathbb C$.